# windows 2000 boot entry for floppy

Tags: boot, windows-2000

Is there a way to create boot entry in windows 2000 boot menu to boot from floppy disk?
Problem is that, that bios is protected with password and i cannot change boot order entries. I cannot open "PC" case, because it is cash register and protected with seal. I need to reprogram cash register keyboard.

Comment: ...not to mention that w2k is a 14-year old OS that reached EOL nearly 4 years ago.

Comment: Question is related to windows 2000. Inside cash register is normal computer parts (standard motherboard, ram, cpu etc.). And with standard windows 2000 setup. Just case is sealed and i cannot reset bios with jumper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but the plop boot manager should let you do this. I've tested this extensively in a VM, and have had no issues, but considering the age of anything with win2k, I'd probably proceed with caution.

You will need the [Plop boot manager](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html) - I used 5.0.14 and an unzipping tool to extract the archive - I used 7zip

Unzip, run "InstallToBootLoader" (you can also use install to mbr but thats messier) script, and agree.

Reboot, and select plop boot manager entry.

[image]

Gaze at the trippy boot screen then select floppy - I'm using a win2000 boot floppy, but you obviously have something else in mind. Do what you need to do.

[image]

Once you're done, remove the entry for plop from boot.ini - this should be in the root of c:, using notepad, and delete the plop folder, if you want to remove plop. Otherwise, leave it alone for the next time you need to boot a cd, usb or floppy